Error while I try to connect with 2 firestore projects from my react web app?
I get the error message 'FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.'
I get this error only when I try to access second firestore('db2'), No problem when accessing 'db1'
In firebase.js:
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
  };

  const firebaseConfig2 = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: "",
  };

const firebaseApp1 = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firebaseApp2 = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig2, "app2");
const db1 = firebaseApp1.firestore();
const db2 = firebaseApp2.firestore();
const auth1 = firebase.auth(firebaseApp1);
const auth2 = firebase.auth(firebaseApp2);
export { db1, auth1, db2, auth2 };

Code that I access 'db2' in a page:
import { db1, db2 } from "./firebase"

const getStudents = async () => {
  const colRef = collection(db2, 'students')
  const q = query(colRef)
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
...
}


From the error message is sounds like the user doesn't have permission to perform the operation on that second database.
Keep in mind that each database in a project has its own security rules. Did you deploy the required security rules to each database?

Yes, both projects have the same security rules. Infact if I swap 'firebaseconfig1' with 'firebaseconfig2' then the second database start to work while the first one does not

It sounds like your configs may be broken then.
